# Query in two table... to build a third

Tags: r, merge

I am looking for a solution to create a table which give species' properties (e.g. altitude) according to criteria from two other tables.

Here are my "original" table:

A first one named "header" which contains informations linked to sampled plot location (altitude, etc.):

```
head(header)
     Hauteur   Alt  Plot    Quadrat   Microhab     Cover
R2   0-50 cm   350   P1      Q1       TA            50
R3   0-50 cm   350   P1      Q1       TA            95
R4   0.5-1 m   350   P1      Q1       TB            50
R5   0.5-1 m   350   P1      Q1       TB            50
...
```

A second one named "datas", which contains species presents in the plots (to use as presence/absence in each plot):

```
head(datas)
        Species a   |   Species b   |   Species c   |  Species x |
    R2 |      1            NA              3               4
    R3 |     NA            1               1               NA
    R4 |      2            1               1               3
    R5 |     NA            NA              3               5
```

I would like to obtain a table which give the "parameters" for each species (example with the altitude). Something like that:

```
head(parametres)
         Altmin  Altmax   Altmoy  nb[350-549] nb[550-749] [...]   %[350-549m]
Species a   800     1600     1300       0          0        ...         0
Species b   600     1800     1350       0          4        ...         0
Species c   1000    1600     1400       0          0        ...         0
```

In this table "parametres", I need to know the min, max & mean altitude of occurrence of each species. Then, I would like to cut the altitude range in classes (from 350m to 2750, with 200m of interval -> nb[350-549]/nb[550-749], etc.) and give for each classes the occurrence number for each species and the percentage (in %[350-549], etc.) of occurrence of each species per class (i.e. the percentage of occurrence of a particular species in a particular class regarding its total number of occurrence).

Any idea?

Comment: In the second data i.e. `datas` there are NA values, which correspond to what in the first dataset?  Also what does those `1, 3, 4, 5` numbers represent?

Comment: In "datas", NA means that the species has not been seen in the sampled plot (the id of the plot are in the first columns for the two tables). Then the values 1, 3, 4, 5 are cover values. In fact for this question, it need to use them just as presence/absence information in the sampled plot).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Somebody will be able to help you with a code.

Comment: Yes I hope ;)      Cheers!